# How can I make headers changeable in this JS script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm new to JS and currently trying to make a table which changes its data automatically. (a 4 years old stackoverflow answer helped me but it's unlikely someone will reply me there).

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dd4xf80v/1/),  part of code below:

```
var data = [data1, data2];
    var i = 0;
    var dt = dynamicTable.config('data-table', 
                                 ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5', 'field6' ], 
                                 ['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3', 'Header4', 'Header5', 'Header6'], //set to null for field names instead of custom header names
                                 'There are no items to list...');

function cycle()
{
    dt.load(data[i % data.length]);
    i++;
    setTimeout(cycle, 2000);
}
cycle();
```

I would like headers to load and change as fields do. I was thinking of 2 solutions

1. delete headers and keep only fields but then the first field won't be styled and it looks bad
2. use code from field spawning function, rename variables and style headers but it didn't work for me

If anyone would point me out if there is a more simple solution or how to do it I'd be more than happy. Thanks for answers.

Comment: How do you want your headers to change? Similar to fields? So that it shows 'new Header 1' etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to swap headers the same way as fields (cycle between 2 sets), something like this would be a quick solution:

- create a headersdata array
- pass it as a parameter to 'public' load method

var headersdata = [headers1, headers2];

```
function cycle() {
    dt.load(data[i % data.length], headersdata[i % data.length]);
    i++;
    setTimeout(cycle, 2000);
}

cycle();
```

- inside load assign your headers data to _headers variable and call 'private' _setHeaders(); function which will use your new headers data now

See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n7fqn2sc/